# wget some website .gif files

Tags: linux, parsing, wget

I tried hard with different options but still i cant wget
http://auno.org/ao/nanos.php?prof=nano-technician
I would like to get all the littles .gif images.

My current request is:

```
wget -A.gif http://auno.org/ao/nanos.php?prof=nano-technician/
```

I tried many options like -O or -U firefox etc.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way you're only downloading the requested page, nothing else. If you want to download more then that, you must turn on recursive downloading (`-r`).

Also, as the images are on different hosts, you may want to enable host spanning (`-H`), and when you do that you should also specify a restrictive recursion limit to avoid downloading half the internet (`-l`):

```
wget -A .gif -r -l 1 -H http://auno.org/ao/nanos.php?prof=nano-technician/
```

Comment: thank you, i had tried -r already but without success, its the -H that makes it all, how did you know the images were on different hosts?

Comment: just by looking at the page source. the gifs src point to sX.auno.org, not on auno.org.